# ZipArchive issues with filesize and no such file Laravel

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, php-ziparchive

I've tried searching all over for a solution to this and tried all that I can, without success. I have a Laravel project that implements photos taken from Amazon S3 storage, and I need to be able to grab all photos from a particular page and zip them up ready for download. However I'm getting various errors depending on how I code it.

This is currently what I have...

First I initialise the `ZipArchive` and then open checking for any possible errors. This code always returns the "All good" response.

```
$zipfile = storage_path() . '/case_photos.zip';
$zip = new ZipArchive;

$ZIP_ERROR = [
    ZipArchive::ER_EXISTS => 'File already exists.',
    ZipArchive::ER_INCONS => 'Zip archive inconsistent.',
    ZipArchive::ER_INVAL => 'Invalid argument.',
    ZipArchive::ER_MEMORY => 'Malloc failure.',
    ZipArchive::ER_NOENT => 'No such file.',
    ZipArchive::ER_NOZIP => 'Not a zip archive.',
    ZipArchive::ER_OPEN => "Can't open file.",
    ZipArchive::ER_READ => 'Read error.',
    ZipArchive::ER_SEEK => 'Seek error.',
];


$result_code = $zip->open($zipfile, ZipArchive::CREATE);
if( $result_code !== true ){
    $msg = isset($ZIP_ERROR[$result_code])? $ZIP_ERROR[$result_code] : 'Unknown error.';
    Log::info("error: " . $msg);
} else {
    Log::info("All good");
}
```

Then I check the photos (taken earlier from the database records) and loop through them, adding them one by one to the previously opened archive.

```
if (!empty($photos)) {
    foreach ($photos as $photo) {
        $sizedPhoto = $this->photoRepo->getPhotoBySize($photo->id, 'large');
        $source = $this->fileStorage->getFileStream($sizedPhoto->storage_name);
        $tmpfname = tempnam(storage_path(), "tmp");
        $destination = fopen($tmpfname, "w");
        while (!feof($source)) {
            fwrite($destination, fread($source,10000));
        }
        fclose($source);
        fclose($destination);
        $zip->addFile($tmpfname, 'photo-'.$photo->id.'.jpg');
        unlink($tmpfname);
    }

    $zip->close();
```

However, this throws the following error on the `$zip-close()` line:

> ZipArchive::close(): Can't open file: No such file or directory

For the sake of testing, I comment this line out and carry on to the download part:

```
$response = new StreamedResponse();
$response->setCallback(function () use($zipfile){
    readfile($zipfile);
    unlink($zipfile);
});


$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/x-zip-compressed');
$response->headers->set('Cache-Control', '');
$response->headers->set('Content-Length', filesize($zipfile));
$response->headers->set('Last-Modified', gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s'));
$contentDisposition = $response->headers->makeDisposition(ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT, basename($zipfile));
$response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', $contentDisposition);

return $response;
```

But then I get this error:

> filesize(): stat failed for
>   /home/vagrant/webapp/storage/case_photos.zip

After going through the photos one by one, I'm finding it difficult to find out the size of each one, because it either tells me it's a resource or the file size is zero.

I wanted to use each photo's size on this line:

```
fwrite($destination, fread($source,10000));
```

Instead of hard-coding a limit of 10000 but I can't get anything to work.

This is getting very frustrating because it seems that whatever I do, I get a 500 error with another problem which I cannot solve. Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

OK so I found out what it was. It turns out the tmp files were being unlinked before they were being added to the zip file - so, essentially the final zip was empty / 0kb which is why it wasn't reading the file size and consequently why it was failing to close the zip.